# It is enough with armeabi-v7a .so libraries for Android 4.0.0 and up versions?

Tags: android

would it be necessary to include  armeabi besides armeabi-v7a for a game which mimimum requirement is Android 4.0.0? There is some specification of the cpu requirements per Android platform? Thanks